# Removing items from JSON using Python loop

Tags: python, json, loops, sorting, filter

how do I iterate over the data and keep object keys that have the string "Java" in the value and remove keys with the string "Javascript" in the value? In addition to the iterations I already have in my code. For example:

this key has the word 'Java' in the value.

```
          "value" : "A vulnerability in the encryption implementation of EBICS messages in the open source librairy ebics-java/ebics-java-client allows an attacker sniffing network traffic to decrypt EBICS payloads. This issue affects: ebics-java/ebics-java-client versions prior to 1.2."
```

the current code below iterates thru other JSON items (that are also needed), but not the Java/Javascript issue.

```
from encodings import utf_8
import json
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from io import BytesIO
import os


url = "https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-2022.json.zip"
urlretrieve(url, "nvdcve-1.1-2022.json.zip")

with ZipFile('nvdcve-1.1-2022.json.zip', 'r') as zip:
    zip.extractall('.')

with open('nvdcve-1.1-2022.json', encoding='utf-8') as x:
    data = json.load(x)

#function to sort through without rewriting code with parameters/arguments passed into the function(variable)  
def base_score(metric):
    if 'baseMetricV3' not in metric['impact']:
        #no values = 0 so it will auto sort by ID
        return (0, metric['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID'])
        #sorts by ID if two or more base scores are equal
    return (metric['impact']['baseMetricV3']['cvssV3']['baseScore'], metric['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID'])
    #return allows assigment of function output to new variable

#direct python to open json file using specific encoding to avoid encoding error

for CVE_Item in data['CVE_Items']:
    for node in CVE_Item['configurations']['nodes']:
        #removes items while iterating through them
        node['cpe_match'][:] = [item for item in node['cpe_match'] if item['vulnerable']]
        #also check children objects for vulnerable 
        if node['children']:
            for children_node in node['children']:
                children_node['cpe_match'][:] = [item for item in children_node['cpe_match'] if item['vulnerable']]

#sorts data in descending order using reverse
data['CVE_Items'].sort(reverse=True, key=base_score)

#write file to current working directory
with open('sorted_nvdcve-1.1-2022.json', 'w') as new_file:
    new_file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

if os.path.exists('nvdcve-1.1-2022.json.zip'):
  os.remove('nvdcve-1.1-2022.json.zip')
else:
  print("The file does not exist") 

if os.path.exists('nvdcve-1.1-2022.json'):
  os.remove('nvdcve-1.1-2022.json')
else:
  print("The file does not exist")
```

here is the link to the original JSON file (too large to post entire text here):
https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-2022.json.zip

the key 'value' is located in the 'description' list.

here is a sample of the JSON text:

```
{
  "CVE_data_type" : "CVE",
  "CVE_data_format" : "MITRE",
  "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
  "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs" : "15972",
  "CVE_data_timestamp" : "2022-11-01T07:00Z",
  "CVE_Items" : [ {
    "cve" : {
      "data_type" : "CVE",
      "data_format" : "MITRE",
      "data_version" : "4.0",
      "CVE_data_meta" : {
        "ID" : "CVE-2022-0001",
        "ASSIGNER" : "secure@intel.com"
      },
      "problemtype" : {
        "problemtype_data" : [ {
          "description" : [ {
            "lang" : "en",
            "value" : "NVD-CWE-noinfo"
          } ]
        } ]
      },
      "references" : {
        "reference_data" : [ {
          "url" : "https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/security-center/advisory/intel-sa-00598.html",
          "name" : "https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/security-center/advisory/intel-sa-00598.html",
          "refsource" : "MISC",
          "tags" : [ "Vendor Advisory" ]
        }, {
          "url" : "http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2022/03/18/2",
          "name" : "[oss-security] 20220318 Xen Security Advisory 398 v2 - Multiple speculative security issues",
          "refsource" : "MLIST",
          "tags" : [ "Mailing List", "Third Party Advisory" ]
        }, {
          "url" : "https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/cpujul2022.html",
          "name" : "N/A",
          "refsource" : "N/A",
          "tags" : [ "Patch", "Third Party Advisory" ]
        }, {
          "url" : "https://security.netapp.com/advisory/ntap-20220818-0004/",
          "name" : "https://security.netapp.com/advisory/ntap-20220818-0004/",
          "refsource" : "CONFIRM",
          "tags" : [ "Third Party Advisory" ]
        } ]
      },
      "description" : {
        "description_data" : [ {
          "lang" : "en",
          "value" : "JavaScript sharing of branch predictor selectors between contexts in some Intel(R) Processors may allow an authorized user to potentially enable information disclosure via local access."
        } ]
      }
```

Comment: Which lists do you want to check for those values?

Comment: the list in the JSON file. I cant post the entire file contents because its too large. I just posted a sample. But, I just need to basically remove any key labeled 'value' that has the word Javascript in it, and keep the ones that have the word Java in it.

Comment: There are LOTS of lists in the JSON file. There's a list inside `problemtype`, a list inside `references`, a list inside `description`, etc.

Comment: The only lists that have `value` keys are in `problemtype` and `description`.

Comment: the list inside description that has the key 'value' in it.

Comment: Why do you have two identical loops that look for `vulnerable`?

Comment: one looks for 'vulnerable' : true in the main list and the other looks under the children lists.

Comment: They both say `#also check children objects for vulnerable`. So they both look in the main list and children.

Comment: Sorry that was my copy/paste mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this inside the `for CVE_Item` loop.

```
CVE_Item['cve']['description']['description_data'] = [
    d for d in CVE_Item['cve']['description']['description_data'] 
    if 'Java' in d['value'] and 'JavaScript' not in d['value']]
```

The modified loop looks like:

```
for CVE_Item in data['CVE_Items']:
    CVE_Item['cve']['description']['description_data'] = [
        d for d in CVE_Item['cve']['description']['description_data'] 
        if 'Java' in d['value'] and 'JavaScript' not in d['value']]
    for node in CVE_Item['configurations']['nodes']:
        #removes items while iterating through them
        node['cpe_match'][:] = [item for item in node['cpe_match'] if item['vulnerable']]
        #also check children objects for vulnerable 
        if node['children']:
            for children_node in node['children']:
                children_node['cpe_match'][:] = [item for item in children_node['cpe_match'] if item['vulnerable']]
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind posting how it should look inside? Sorry I'm still very new to coding.

Comment: I added it, although I think it should be obvious. You just stick that exact code right into the loop.

Comment: You are right! I just wanted to make sure I wasnt making a mistake. Thank you again.